# Hyper-V VMs can't reach external network

Tags: routing, vmware-esxi, hyper-v

I run a small ESXi Homelab and all of my VMs run on the 10.0.0.x subnet, and this is bridged out to a switch where my local PC is connected to - so I have access to everything on the 10.0.0.x subnet.

All of my VMs can connect to the internet without issue. One of my VMs is running Hyper-V Server 2016 (the standalone, not Windows role) and is connected up to the network the same as all of the other VMs and can access the internet.

However, none of the Hyper-V VMs can reach the external network, despite being statically assigned IPs in their respective Network Configurations. All of the VMs are connected directly to an External Hyper-V Switch, which is connected to the Hyper-V Server NIC, which is connected to the 10.0.0.x LAN.

The VMs can reach 10.0.0.2 (Hyper-V Server IP) but nothing outside of this. The firewall is disabled on the machine I am trying to ping (and works from other ESXi VMs) but still doesn't work.

Occasionally when pinging I get the "Destination Host Unreachable" error in CMD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable MAC address spoofing in order for the nested Hyper-V VM's to communicate on the external physical network.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/nested-virtualization

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've enabled MAC Address spoofing on the ESXi Switch and Hyper-V switch but neither has worked unfortunately.

Comment: Nevermind - ESXi reboot solved issue. Cheers